# Compute File MD5 using Swift in ios

Tags: ios, swift, md5, md5sum, md5-file

Is there any library to compute a fileMD5 in swift ios, more efficiently for big files, if not please give me some ideas to compute a file md5 for large files?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:
1) Add this to your project:

```
extension NSData {
func MD5() -> NSString {
    let digestLength = Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH)
    let md5Buffer = UnsafeMutablePointer<CUnsignedChar>.allocate(capacity: digestLength)

    CC_MD5(bytes, CC_LONG(length), md5Buffer)
    let output = NSMutableString(capacity: Int(CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2))
    for i in 0..<digestLength {
        output.appendFormat("%02x", md5Buffer[i])
    }

    return NSString(format: output)
    }
}
```

2) Create a bridging header adding this:

```
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCrypto.h>
```